# Show that $\mathbb{N}$ and $\{10, 20, 30, 40, ...\}$ are of equal size

Tags: functions

I know that we have to find a bijection between the two sets in order to prove that they have the same cardinality.

Let's consider $A = \{10, 20, 30, 40, ...\}$

I assumed the following:
$$f:\mathbb N\to A \\ f(n)=10n$$
I eventually found that $y=10n \implies n = \dfrac{y}{10}$, but I do not know how to prove that $\dfrac{y}{10} \in \mathbb N$.

I also tried $f:A\to \mathbb N$ with $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{10}$ but I couldn't prove that $10y \in A$ either.

I searched online but couldn't find something similar, I would highly appreciate any hint.

Comment: You don't need to prove that y/10 is an integer because y/10= n and you have defined n as a member of N, the set of positive integers.

Comment: $f$ is a bijection because each $y \in A$ is a multiple of $10$. Also, $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb N$ so it is in fact enough to show that $f$ is an injection.

Comment: If $y = 10n; n \in \mathbb N$ then $\frac y{10} = \frac {10n}{10} = n$ and $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: The problem with this question is that you pretty much have to assume or guess just what the set $A$ is.  We know $10,20,30,40$ are the first four elements but what's the next? is if $57$.  Do we know if $80$ is in it?  I'm being silly but as you discovered to prove $f(n) =10n$ is onto we must prove that if $y\in A$ then $\frac y{10}\in \mathbb N$. And... we can't really prove that unless we actually have a way of describing what $A$ *is*.  And it's clear that $A$ *is* the set of multiples of $10$. So $\frac y{10}\in \mathbb N$ by *definition*! ... if we had a definition, that is....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is we need a *definition* for $A=\{10,20,30, 40,....\}$ and it's pretty clear that the intended definition is $A = \{10n| n\in \mathbb N\}$.  We can't *prove* that.  It's just a given.

And if we have it as the definition of what $A$ is then proving:

> For any $y \in A$ then $\frac y{10}\in \mathbb N$

is pretty much a given.  By *definition* if $y \in A$ then there exist an $n\in \mathbb N$ so that $y =10n$.  That is what being in $A$ *means*.

So $\frac y{10}= \frac {10n}{10} = n$ and $n\in \mathbb N$.  That's the proof.  That's all you need.

If we want to get around formally defining $A = \{10n|n\in \mathbb N\}$ (perhaps we are new to set definition and it makes things too confusing) we can still do it if we have some way to *describe* $A$.  It could be as simple (and handwavey) as this:

If $y \in A$ then $y$ is a positive number that ends in a zero.  But a number that ends with a zero is a multiple of $10$.  If $y= \overline{a_k....a_2a_10}$ then $y = \overline{a_k.....a_2a_1}\times 10$. And so $\frac y{10} = \overline{a_k.....a_2a_1}$ which is a natural number.

But somehow we are *assuming* that $A$ is just the set of all multiples of $10$. And that's okay because that *has* to be one way or another what $A$ is meant to be.

Comment: That's a very clear answer. Thank you!